Deleting Item in Livewire Modal shows 404 not found pop up
I am using livewire modal from this repo: https://github.com/wire-elements/modal
So, I create an edit modal where it can also delete the item. Here is the modal look like

There are delete button. When I click that, its actually deleted. No error given, and the modal closed but after a second there is another pop up showing 404 not found

Even I cannot add another account, when I click a button to add another account it keeps showing 404 not found. The only way to solve this is to refresh the page then its working normally.
Here is the delete function from AccountMediumEditModal.php
public function delete()
{
    // Check if account medium still exists
    if (!$this->accountMedium->exists) {
        $this->dispatch('show-toast', ['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'The item has already been deleted.']);
        return;
    }
    $controllerAccountMedium = new AccountMediumController();
    $res = $controllerAccountMedium->destroy(accountMedium: $this->accountMedium);

    if ($res->status() != 200) {
        $this->dispatch('show-toast', ['status' => 'error', 'message' => $res->getData()->message]);
        return;
    }

    $this->dispatch('show-toast', ['status' => 'success', 'message' => $res->getData()->message]);
    $this->closeModal();
    $this->destroyOnClose();
}

Here is the complete code if you wish to see it in full mode
class AccountMediumEditModal extends ModalComponent
{
    public AccountMedium $accountMedium;
    public $projectCategories;
    public $mediumAccount;

    // Model
    public $created_by;
    public $account_medium_id;
    public $allowed_categories = [];
    public $recommended_password;
    public $name;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $blog_url;
    public $token;
    public $token_expired_at;

    public function mount()
    {

        if ($this->accountMedium) {
            $this->created_by = $this->accountMedium->created_by;
            $this->recommended_password = $this->accountMedium->recommended_password;
            $this->name = $this->accountMedium->name;
            $this->allowed_categories = $this->accountMedium->allowed_categories;
            $this->username = $this->accountMedium->username;
            $this->password = $this->accountMedium->password;
            $this->blog_url = $this->accountMedium->blog_url;
            $this->token = $this->accountMedium->token;
            $this->token_expired_at = $this->accountMedium->token_expired_at;
        }
    }
    public function render()
    {
        // Define token expiration +2 month by default
        if (!$this->token_expired_at) {
            $currentTime = Carbon::now();
            $this->token_expired_at = $currentTime->modify('+2 month')->format('Y-m-d\TH:i');
        }
        // Define recommended password to use
        $this->recommended_password = $this->accountMedium->account->recommended_password;
        // Get project category
        $this->projectCategories = ProjectCategory::all();
        return view('livewire.modal.account.account-medium-edit-modal');
    }

    protected $rules = [];
    public function edit()
    {
        $this->account_medium_id = $this->accountMedium->id;
        $this->created_by = Auth::user()->id;

        // Replacing http with https
        $this->blog_url = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $this->blog_url);
        // Fix when blog_url has no https
        if (!Str::contains($this->blog_url, 'https://')) {
            $this->blog_url = 'https://' . $this->blog_url;
        }
        $accountMediumEditRequest = new AccountMediumEditRequest();
        $this->rules = $accountMediumEditRequest->rules();
        $input = $this->validate();
        $accountMediumEditRequest->merge($input);

        $controllerAccountMedium = new AccountMediumController();
        $res = $controllerAccountMedium->update(accountMediumEditRequest: $accountMediumEditRequest);

        if ($res->status() != 200) {
            $this->dispatch('show-toast', ['status' => 'error', 'message' => $res->getData()->message]);
            return;
        }

        $this->dispatch('show-toast', ['status' => 'success', 'message' => $res->getData()->message]);
        $this->dispatch('refresh');
        $this->closeModal();
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        // Check if account medium still exists
        if (!$this->accountMedium->exists) {
            $this->dispatch('show-toast', ['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'The item has already been deleted.']);
            return;
        }
        $controllerAccountMedium = new AccountMediumController();
        $res = $controllerAccountMedium->destroy(accountMedium: $this->accountMedium);

        if ($res->status() != 200) {
            $this->dispatch('show-toast', ['status' => 'error', 'message' => $res->getData()->message]);
            return;
        }

        $this->dispatch('show-toast', ['status' => 'success', 'message' => $res->getData()->message]);
        $this->dispatch('refresh');
        $this->closeModal();
        $this->destroyOnClose();
    }
}


You haven't shared any information about the routes. The error cannot be reproduced. Does the route exist?

After $this->destroyOnClose(); (whatever it does) add $this->reset();
If you encounter an error, you may have to add a default value to all your public vars, for example
public $name = '';
Methink, the residue of your settings forces the modal to reopen. Hard to tell as you don't share the ModalComponent.
By the way, and unrelated, in the future you can simply do
if ($this->accountMedium) {
   $this->fill($this->accountMedium);
}

a handy Livewire trick.
